# Devise not authenticating in Rails 3.2.8 or without account_id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

After signing in, a user is redirected a controller that is protected by authenticate_user!:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

In Rails 3.2.8, this does not authenticate and returns 'Completed 401 Unauthorized'.

However, it works with Rails 3.2.7, but ONLY if I add the account_id to the form (HAML)

```
= f.hidden_field :account_id, :value => @account.id
```

With that hidden field added, I see this query in the log:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'email@gmail.com' AND "users"."account_id" = 41 LIMIT 1
```

However, when I remove the account_id hidden field, no query for the user is performed, and the logs show same 'Completed 401 Unauthorized' message.

It doesn't work in Rails 3.2.8, with or without the account_id.

I'm on the latest Devise (2.1.2)

This issue has been bugging me for a long time, so any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have this in my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords", :sessions => "sessions", :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

and my initializers/devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Mailer Configuration
  # Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in DeviseMailer.
  config.mailer_sender = "info@mydomain.com"

  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # omniauth stuff
  require "omniauth-facebook"
  require 'openid/store/filesystem'
  config.omniauth :facebook, "#key", "#secret"
  config.omniauth :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id', :require => 'omniauth-openid'

  # ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
  # Configure which keys are used when authenticating a user. The default is
  # just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
  # authenticating a user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
  # parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
  # session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
  # You can also supply a hash where the value is a boolean determining whether
  # or not authentication should be aborted when the value is not present.
  config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :account_id ]


  # Configure which authentication keys should be case-insensitive.
  # These keys will be downcased upon creating or modifying a user and when used
  # to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  # Configure which authentication keys should have whitespace stripped.
  # These keys will have whitespace before and after removed upon creating or
  # modifying a user and when used to authenticate or find a user. Default is :email.
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.stretches = 10

  config.reset_password_within = 2.hours
  config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :mobile]

  config.sign_out_via = :delete

end
```

Comment: Can you post the `devise.rb` file in `config/initializers`? Also are you overriding the devise sessions controller in any way? It would be in your routes file, looking something like `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'users/sessions'}`.

Comment: @BrettBender thanks, updated post with that info.  Why would overriding the sessions controller affect it?  I've only overridden #sessions/new (to use a different layout)

Comment: @BrettBender no longer overriding #sessions/new (just added layout 'login') to top of sessions controller.  Issue is still occurring.